# how to save html table into excel file format using javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, excel, laravel-4

Iam trying to save html(blade.php file)table into excel file in laravel.
my javascript code

```
function exportToExcel() {
    var htmls = "";
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'; 
    var base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    };
    var format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
           return c[p];
        })
    };
    htmls = "YOUR HTML AS TABLE"
    var ctx = {
        worksheet : 'Worksheet',
        table : htmls
    }
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "export.xls";
    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    link.click();
}
```

Button is

`<input type="button" onclick="exportToExcel()" value="Export to Excel">`

it works fine.

but, problem is ,its only works in Chrome and microsoft-office:excel.
not work in other browsers(IE7+, Firefox etc) and open office 4(open office calc,open office math etc) software.

what iam do ?? how to add other softwares and browsers into my code??

but only display "YOUR HTML AS TABLE".not my table values.

Comment: In what way does it "not work" in other browsers? Error messages?

Comment: no error message. if click button no action. if in chrome work and display in excel file only  YOUR HTML AS TABLE in one cell. not my table values.

Comment: Your sending all your data via the uri query string, how big is that data? chrome has a pretty huge limit on the length of query strings compared to other browsers which could be why it only works in chrome. You may be better posting the table data to a controller via an ajax request and returning the url for the file.

Comment: my table have 3 fields code is  <table class="table table-hover" >
                    <tr class="tbl-head">
                      <td>Teacher</td>
                      <td>Mobile</td>
                   
                      <td>Type</td>
                    </tr> 
                    @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
                      <tr><td>{{$teacher->tname}}</td>
                          <td>{{$teacher->tmobile}}</td>
                          @if($teacher->ttype == 1)
                            <td>Class Teacher</td><tr/></table>

Answer (score 0):

U can use jsfiddle file saver library

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/XNVj3/1/

and use as below :

```
var nameXclVar = new Blob([TblHtmCodVar], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });

saveAs(nameXclVar, "NamXcl.xls");
```